# ActionScript: after movie finish load URL

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

how to make flash after finish the movie, then it will go to URL i choose?

Comment: Is your movie on the "timeline", is it a video or is the movie all actionscript? If it's timeline you can put a frame label on the last frame, and then add a framescript that dispatches an event when it reaches that frame...

Comment: this the movie flash. let says this is flash intro, when the intro is finish, then it will got to different url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well...

Use `navigateToURL` : http://bit.ly/fVvlxm

In the last frame of your MovieClip :

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://yoururl.com"),"_self");
```

OR

```
movieClip.addFrameScript(test.totalFrames-1, function() : void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://yoururl.com"),"_blank");
});
```

Comment: strange... could you please provide more information about your environement ?

Comment: oh sorry my bad, i didn't notice it take too long to open Firefox browser. thank you, your code is work. my computer is slow to open firefox :)